# Arduino to Processing, Strings ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18

Tags: arrays, string, arduino, processing

I'm working on a program which sends messages from Arduino to Processing, printing them to the serial port from arduino as decimal numbers, then picking them up in a string array in processing. The problem I"m getting is: "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds:18" and it highlights the line that says dlay = Integer.parseInt(B[18]), I assume the array isn't big enough to store anything past 17, and I'm probably making a really stupid mistake but I can't figure out how to extend it!

Any suggestions?

Thanks so much in advance!

```
import processing.serial.*; //import the Serial library

int end = 10;
String serial;
Serial port;
int c;
int d;
int e;
int f;
int g;
int a;
int b;
int C;
int p1t;
int p2t;
int p3t;
int p4t;
int p5t;
int p6t;
int p7t;
int p8t;
int pan;
int reverb;
int dlay;
int distort;
//ellipse parameters
int noteOn = 0;
int col1 = 0;
int col2 = 0;
int col3 = 0;
String[] A;
String[] B;
void setup() {
    size(600,600);
    frameRate(30);
    port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[7], 115200);
    port.clear();
    serial = port.readStringUntil(end);
    serial = null; // initially, the string will be null (empty)
}

void draw() {

while (port.available() > 0) { 
serial = port.readStringUntil(end);

}
if (serial != null) {  //if the string is not empty, print the following

  A = split(serial, ','); 
  B = trim(A);
  c = Integer.parseInt(B[1]);
  if (c == 1){
  col1 = 255;
  col2 = 0;
  col3 = 0;
  }
  d = Integer.parseInt(B[2]);
  if (d == 1){
  col1 = 0;
  col2 = 0;
  col3 = 255;
  }
  e = Integer.parseInt(B[3]);
  if (e == 1){
  col1 = 0;
  col2 = 255;
  col3 = 0;
  }
  f = Integer.parseInt(B[4]);
  if (f == 1){
  col1 = 255;
  col2 = 0;
  col3 = 255;
  }
  g = Integer.parseInt(B[5]);
  if (g == 1){
  col1 = 255;
  col2 = 255;
  col3 = 0;
  }
  a = Integer.parseInt(B[6]);
  if (a == 1){
  col1 = 0;
  col2 = 255;
  col3 = 255;
  }
  b = Integer.parseInt(B[7]);
  if (b == 1){
  col1 = 50;
  col2 = 250;
  col3 = 130;
  }
  C = Integer.parseInt(B[8]);
  if (C == 1){
  col1 = 200;
  col2 = 90;
  col3 = 75;
  }
if(c == 1 || d == 1 || e == 1 || f == 1 || g == 1 || a == 1 || b == 1 || C == 1){
  noteOn = 1;
}
else {
  noteOn = 0;
}
p1t = Integer.parseInt(B[9]);
p2t = Integer.parseInt(B[10]);
p3t = Integer.parseInt(B[11]);
p4t = Integer.parseInt(B[12]);
p5t = Integer.parseInt(B[13]);
p6t = Integer.parseInt(B[14]);
p7t = Integer.parseInt(B[15]);
p8t = Integer.parseInt(B[16]);
pan = Integer.parseInt(B[17]);
dlay = Integer.parseInt(B[18]);
//reverb = Integer.parseInt(B[19]);
//distort = Integer.parseInt(B[18]);
} 
fill(0, 0,0, 255);
rect(0,0, 600,600);
fill(col1,col2, col3); 
ellipse(300+pan, 300, (noteOn*p8t), (noteOn*p8t));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that arrays in Java (and therefore Processing as well) start their indexing at `0`, not `1`? That is, the first element of an array called `exampleArray` is accessed by writing `exampleArray[0]`, the second is accessed with `exampleArray[1]`, etc. So if there are 18 elements in your array, writing `B[18]` is actually trying to get a nonexistent 19th element.

A side note: it's considered poor practice to have so many variables, especially with such short names-- I have no idea what `a`, `b`, `c`, etc are doing by looking at their names, and the later code doesn't explain it either. This is compounded by the fact that there are both lower- and upper-case versions of some of the letters! You know what they are now, but if you come back to this code in a few months then you'll have to figure it out.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer! The variable names are notes, so lower case c is the note c, d e f g a b, upper case C is the note C an octave above. How can I avoid having all these variables though? Since they all must be converted and used to control different things? And I'm aware of the zero index, but even when i put 50 in the square brackets, I still get the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 18, when I add in the 18th integer.ParseInt line, do you know whether strings have a certain length or something? I really can't figure it out!

Comment: If you insert `println(B);` immediately after you call `B = trim(A);`, what do you see?